# Does this series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$

I'm trying to use the root test and wondering if my steps are correct.

First I rewrote the problem:

$\frac{n4^n}{5^n}$

Then I did the following:

$\lim \text{sup}\left|\frac{n^\frac{1}{n}\left(4^n\right)^\frac{1}{n}}{\left(5^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right|$

Which basically equals:

$\lim \text{sup}\left|\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}(4)}{5}\right|=\frac{4}{5}\lim \text{sup}n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

And so $\frac{4}{5} \lt 1$ so it converges.

Is this correct?

Comment: trivia: $\sum_{n=1}^N n\cdot r^n < \sum_{n=1}^N (n+1)\cdot r^n = \frac{d}{dr}\sum_{n=1}^N r^{n+1} = \frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r^{N+2}-1}{r-1}\right)$ when $r<1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good! The ratio test is possibly easier here, since it boils down to

$$\frac{4}{5} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n}$$

so you don't have to know that $\lim n^{1/n} = 1$.